# Is it against the rules of Bootstrap to have non-row element wrapping a group of col elements?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

E.g.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="not-a-bs-class">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I could nest a col-md-12 and another row, but this seems to work, but is it the kind of thing that is against the rules, so to speak?

Comment: I doing that many times

Comment: it's fine, but if you have any margins or padding or borders on that div, the columns may not behave as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This violates [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro), but if it works for you then there's no problem:

> Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows.